# Acumatica Rest API get customer attribute name

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to obtain values for Customer attributes via the Rest API.   Currently, I can retrieve customer attributes, but am unable to determine which specific attribute is associated.  For example, given this code (based on https://github.com/Acumatica/AcumaticaRESTAPIClientForCSharp,  Endpoint = "Default", EndpointVersion = "18.200.001", Endpoint Library = Acumatica.Default_20.200.001, Acumatica version = Cloud ERP 2020 R1, Build 20.110.0017):

```
            var customerApi = new CustomerApi(configuration);
            var customers = customerApi.GetList(top: 5, expand: "Attributes", select: "Attributes/Attribute,Attributes/Value");

            foreach (var cust in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cust.ToString());
            }
```

Yields this output:

```
{
  
"AccountRef": {},
  "Attributes": [
    {
      "Value": {
        "value": "True"
      },
      "id": "8de7a85d-6d60-4235-9d35-74a9d08d1cc6",
      "rowNumber": 1,
      "custom": {}
    },
    {
      "Value": {
        "value": "Sample Email Body"
      },
      "id": "8da2a21c-2ba3-45ba-9e12-02122c626e11",
      "rowNumber": 2,
      "custom": {}
    }, ...
```

[image]

[image]

What am I missing to be able to get the attribute name returned as well?  Or how I am supposed to correlate the given values back to a given attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration of the Customers API is returning the `Attributes` array as below for the `customerApi.GetList(top: 5, expand: "Attributes", select: "Attributes/Attribute,Attributes/Value");` request

```
 "Attributes": [
    {
      "Attribute": {
        "value": "Company Revenue"
      },
      "Value": {
        "value": "1,000,000 to 5,000,000"
      },
      "id": "6df69428-7157-438f-8b61-99b2d7d1a3ad",
      "rowNumber": 1,
      "custom": {}
    },
    {
      "Attribute": {
        "value": "Number of Employees"
      },
      "Value": {
        "value": "1-100"
      },
      "id": "15c3f47f-36eb-481b-92c0-f6b2f738732f",
      "rowNumber": 2,
      "custom": {}
    }
  ]
```

**Attributes->Attribute->Value** is the identifier for the Attribute which is corresponding to the Description of the Attribute record.

Your result is returned for `customerApi.GetList(top: 5, expand: "Attributes", select: "Attributes/Value");` request. Please make sure that you have included the Attributes/Attribute in the select part if you are specifying it.

[image]

**UPDATE**

There is a small difference in naming between 18.200 and 20.200.

> In 18.200 the Attribute ID is actually named Attribute
> In 20.200 the Attribute ID is renamed to Attribute ID

That is why this request is working correctly for 18.200

```
namespace Acumatica.Default_18_200_001.Model
{
    [DataContract]
    public class AttributeDetail : Entity_v3
    {

        [DataMember(Name="Attribute", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public StringValue Attribute { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="RefNoteID", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public GuidValue RefNoteID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="Required", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public BooleanValue Required { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="Value", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public StringValue Value { get; set; }

    }
}



namespace Acumatica.Default_20_200_001.Model
{
    [DataContract]
    public class AttributeValue : Entity_v4
    {

        [DataMember(Name="AttributeID", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public StringValue AttributeID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="AttributeDescription", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public StringValue AttributeDescription { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="RefNoteID", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public GuidValue RefNoteID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="Required", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public BooleanValue Required { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="Value", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public StringValue Value { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="ValueDescription", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public StringValue ValueDescription { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am making the call as specified with the proper **select** value.  I have learned from your response that **Attributes->Attribute->Value** should return the attribute description and not the attribute Id.  Double checking my dataset, the attribute descriptions are populated.  I am wondering if somehow my dataset is otherwise misconfigured?

Comment: @Jubilsoft-Scott Could you please add a screenshot of your customer's attribute tab to the question? Have you changed anything in the Web Service Endpoints page?

Comment: Turns out this is a library issue.  My test project was utilizing the Acumatica.Default_20.200.001 library instead of the Acumatica.Default_18.200.001 library.  Switching to the version 18 library garnered the desired output.

Comment: @Jubilsoft-Scott I have updated the answer with details on why the request is not working in 20.200